# Firefox 49 cannot display radio and checkbox inputs on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox

Today I have updated Firefox to the latest version 49 on my Ubuntu 14.04 (using `apt-get upgrade`). It is very weird that Firefox does not display the radio and checkbox inputs correctly (see the screenshot below: it should display a square before **Check me out**). Any ideas on what is the problem? Thanks a lot.

[image: Firefox]

Comment: This is a bug in FF49 so report it on launchpad.